# rspec - Not yet implemented message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I'm still very new to this and I was trying to test a very basic controller function, just to get started, but I keep getting the pending message:

> Pending: Failures listed here are expected and do not affect your suite's status

There's probably something small I'm not seeing or forgetting... Some help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have in the `spec>controllers>reviews_controller_spec.rb` file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ReviewsController do
 describe "GET #index" do
  it "gets index"
 end
end
```

This is in my controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @reviews = Review.all
 end

 def new
  @review = Review.new
 end

 def create
  review_params = params.require( :review ).permit( :title, :rating )

  @review = Review.new( review_params )

  if @review.save
     redirect_to @review
  else
     render 'new'
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Looks like `pending` tests may be in other test file. You may search for calls to `pending` in `spec/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that message because you haven't filled out at least one of your tests.  In this case, it looks like your `it "gets index"` test.  Rspec is just reminding you that the implementation of this test is pending.  It's fine.  It's common practice to fill out the overall structure of your tests first with "it" statements and then filling in the tests later.  Also if you use `rails generate` and have it set up with rspec, then often rspec creates the template for relevant tests in your controller or helper folders, for example, and those tests are also "pending" to start out with

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. I thought I'd make a very basic test first, but I guess it's too basic and not even testing anything... Thanks!

Comment: no prob..edited to give a fuller answer...if you found my answer helpful please don't forget to accept it